# javascript turn float-allocated number into smaller unsigned numbers

Tags: javascript, binary, compression

[in javascript numbers are always allocated as double precision floats](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp). This is fine if you aren't sending huge amounts of these as binary without compression, or don't need to conserve memory. If you need to make these numbers smaller how do you do so?

The obvious goal would be to store numbers into the smallest possible byte size, for example 208 : 1 byte, 504 : 2 bytes. Even better would be smallest number of bit size, for example 208 : 8 bits, 504 : 9 bits.

example:

```
    //myNetwork is a supposed network API that sends as binary

    var x = 208;

    myNetwork.send(x); // sends 01000011010100000000000000000000
    myNetwork.send(x.toString()); //sends 001100100011000000111000
```

There is also [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), but turning into a typed array is tricky if it isn't already a blob or file. On certain network APIs in Javascript the raw data is often represented as a string before you can touch it.

Answer (score 0):

encoding

```
//myNetwork is a supposed network API that sends as binary

var x = 208;

myNetwork.send(String.fromCharCode(x)); //sends 11010000 , also known as Ð
```

decoding

```
var receivedString = "Ð";

var decodedNum = receivedString.charCodeAt(0); //208
```

The string method mentioned is 24 bits, whereas this is only 8 bits.

The drawback of this method is that there is obviously some waste if you want less than byte sized values. For example, you should be able to store 512 values in 9 bits, however you'd be forced to go up to 16 bits (2 bytes) which is 65,535 values because in unicode characters are all byte-sized. However, it is fine if you'll be utilizing the full range of values.